# Error spotipy.oauth2.SpotifyOauthError: You must either set a cache_path or a username

Tags: python, python-3.x, spotify, spotipy

When I try to run this code:

```
scope = 'playlist-modify-public'
sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=SpotifyOAuth(scope=scope))
sp.user_playlist_create(username_id, 'YouTube Converter PL', public=True, description='Test')
```

I get the error spotipy.oauth2.SpotifyOauthError: You must either set a cache_path or a username.

I have all the env variables set up.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to go around this by passing in cache_path and redirect_uri:

```
scope = 'playlist-modify-public'
OAuth = SpotifyOAuth(scope=scope,
    redirect_uri='http://localhost:8888/callback',
    cache_path='D:/MyProjects/YTtoSpotify')
sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=OAuth)
sp.user_playlist_create(username_id, 'YouTube Converter PL', public=True, 
    description='Youtube Playlist converted using https://github.com/mider111/YTtoSpotify')
```

Now the code works and creates a playlist in my profile.
There is definitely something wrong with SpotifyOAuth though.